# python stream data between sources

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a large file in my FTP, and I need to write it to google cloud storage.
My first thought would be download it from ftp to local file, and then transmit local file to remote storage. But I would prefer to do it without downloading it localy.
So far I came up with the following code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import io

ftp = ftp = FTP('example.com')
ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
sock = ftp.transfercmd('RETR file.csv')
raw = io.BytesIO()
file = io.BufferedRandom(raw)

blob = bucket.blob('blobname.csv', chunk_size=262144)  # gcs blob
blob.upload_from_file(file, content_type='text/csv', rewind=True)
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsh/example.py", line 65, in <module>
    file = io.BufferedRandom(raw)
io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
```

Is there a way to pipe data from ftp to cloud storage (or any other remote resource) without downloading it to local machine? I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want, without python, using [rclone](https://rclone.org/). If you *must* use python, maybe they provide a wrapper or you could use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting rclone, but I need to do it in pure python, without subprocess.